# Master webserver, many slaves, one database

Tags: database, .htaccess, webserver

I have one webserver with a webpage in a single CMS in multible languages stored in a single database.

I now have to move each country site to an IP so an geo_ip_lookup will return correct country. Apparently that is good for SEO. So my issue is not load balancing or performance issue, just to find a way (or workaround) to access the webpage from multible contries and IP's from these contries (one domain for each country, domain.com, domain.de, domain.fr, domain.cn etc.).

What would be best practice? I need to keep just one central database. My focus if on reasonable maintenance afterwards.

1) solution with multible webservers and just a single database server
install multible copies of same CMS on multible servers. Set them all up to using the same database on same database server

2) crazy light weight solution:
I have spend 45min to create a simple script to place in a single php-file on "slave" servers. Basically the "slave script" load the correct page from the "master" server and just rewrites the URL's in the html before returning it to the client so it look like that the page exist on the slave server. A bit of overhead is added, but it seems acceptable. Action on forms have to be rewritten though. Could something like this be a solution?

3) Database replication.
Never tried it. Not sure I am game for it.

4) something else and mich better?

BR. Anders

Comment: In option 1 you shift the delay between "client->site" to "site->database", it might only slightly improve the client's loadtime. Option 2 is basically a proxy, does not improve the loadtime at all. Option 3 can work, depending on what changes you make in the database. If all servers must be able to write to the database, than you need to setup a master1->master2->master3->master1 replication (for 3 servers). If one fails, the circle is broken and the replication fails. (not a problem with 2 master servers). My recommandation: let a inernational hosting company handle the "geo load balance"

Comment: Yes, but the issue is not so much the load and response times. It is more that the customer want each country site placed on an IP in its own country (SEO guy recommends this). But all sites run in one single CMS installation and that has to stay like that since a large catalog of is shared between sites. Ressources can be placed in CDN to limit load to the pure html.